# 2 Queries to do the same thing not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 queries. The first is what I want to accomplish, however, it was taking much too long. Here's how the query looked like:

```
SELECT *
FROM old_table
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM new_table)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM new_table
```

Basically, I want everything that's in the old table, but not in the new table. I then union everything from the old and new. Again, this query was taking much too long on a bigger dataset. So, I optimized it like so:

```
WITH union_tbl AS (
    (SELECT * FROM old_table)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT * FROM new_table)
), row_tbl AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ordering) AS row
    FROM union_tbl
) 
SELECT *
FROM row_tbl
WHERE row = 1
```

In the old_table and new_table (in a separate query) I add a new column to each called ordering. The new_table gets 1 for all its rows. For the old table, it gets 2 for all its rows. In the end, I select where the row number is 1. So that means if there's 2 rows one for new_table and one for old_table then it should get the new_table row instead.

This is how I'm envisioning it, however, I'm not getting the same results as my previous query. I'd expect it to have the same exact results with the same rows. What am I getting wrong? Is my query logic incorrect?

Comment: please enter part of the sample data and part of your desired output.

Comment: You need to isolate the data in question and inspect it to see what the issue is. Also you could try changing your original query to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` and see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below code?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM old_table a left join new_table b on a.id=b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM new_table
```

This is a very optimized way